# windows 8 RDP Child Session - how to use?

Tags: c#, rdp

I trying to use RDP child sessions as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553447(v=vs.85).aspx

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.Server = "localhost";
    Object True = true;
    MSTSCLib.IMsRdpExtendedSettings extSettings = (MSTSCLib.IMsRdpExtendedSettings)axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx();
    extSettings.set_Property("ConnectToChildSession", True);
    axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.Connect();
}
```

But I get an exception on the method Connect():

> "Value does not fall within extended range".

Сan anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Credential Security Service Provider Support in order to connect to a client session.

Do this before you connect...

```
IMsRdpClient7 msRdpClient = this.axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx() as IMsRdpClient7;
msRdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
```